# При вызове функции qDebug происходит аварийное завершение QT6

Tags: c++, mingw, qt6

ОС : Windows 10, Компилятор : mingw64(установлен с помощью msys), QT : 6.6.1(установлен с помощью msys). Проблема : При добавлении вызова функции qDebug в функции main происходит аварийное завершение программы, в консоли следующее сообщение:
HEAP[test_sql.exe]:
Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 0000000000770000, 000000000063AA10 )
Если убрать qDebug, то проект запускается без ошибок
Пробовал: Переустанавливать QT, пересобирать проект. Если запускать через дебаггер, то он останавливается в деструкторе класса QArrayDataPointer.
Сам код :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Hello";
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Покажите конструктор `MainWindow`.

Comment: Добавил файл реализации

Comment: Похоже, какая-то бинарная несовместимость.

Comment: Столкнулся с несовместимостью библиотек от msys и microsoft. Поэтому под виндой использую только сборки с помощью MSVC 2022. И да, описанная проблема с 6.6.1 у меня отсутствует, я использую конструкцию qDebug активно, но сборка QT 6.6.1 у меня собственная из исходников.